# RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point dtype can require gradients

Tags: python, pytorch

RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point dtype can require gradients

got following error from

> input = Variable(preprocessed_img, requires_grad = True)

```
img=train_loader.dataset.data[0]
print(type(img))
img_tensor = torch.tensor(img)
preprocess_image(img)

> def preprocess_image(img):    means=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406]     stds=[0.229,
> 0.224, 0.225]
> 
>   preprocessed_img = img.copy()[: , :, ::-1]  for i in range(3):
>       preprocessed_img[:, :, i] = preprocessed_img[:, :, i] - means[i]
>       preprocessed_img[:, :, i] = preprocessed_img[:, :, i] / stds[i]
>   preprocessed_img = \
>       np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(preprocessed_img, (2, 0, 1)))
>   preprocessed_img = torch.from_numpy(preprocessed_img)
>   preprocessed_img.unsqueeze_(0)  input = Variable(preprocessed_img,
> requires_grad = True)     return input
```

Comment: you should specify the type when using torch.tensor. If you use torch.Tensor, the framework infers the type directly hence below Ashish answer should also work

Answer (score 2):

Use `torch.Tensor(img)` instead of `torch.tensor(img)`. This should probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.Tensor` does not take `requires_grad`, and `torch.tensor` needs `dtype`.

```
img_tensor = torch.tensor(img, dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
```